# JSDoc comments for destructuring parameters not working in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, jsdoc3

According to [the doc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties), JSDoc supports destructuring parameters:

```
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function({ name, department }) {
    // ...
};
```

However, it doesn't work for me in VSCode (v1.23.1). Has anyone successfully tried this?

VSCode and TypeScript repos contain several posts about similar issues, but they are confusing and closed (example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22980)).

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? If I paste that code into a file and put a constructor function declaration in front of it, then use `const p = new Project();`, typing `p.assign(` shows me the JSDoc for the `employee` parameter. (And I see that it's destructured, though I don't see the documentation for `employee.name` and `.department`.) Is that what you mean? (Interestingly: If you leave off the first `@param` above, what you see when you type `p.assign(` looks a lot like one would want...)

Comment: "though I don't see the documentation for employee.name and .department": that is one problem, the other one being that you cannot see the correct parameter types. This prevents [automatic type checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking) from working correctly in many cases.

Comment: The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19645#issuecomment-395050077)

Answer (score 3):

This feature is supported from VSCode 1.24 only (TypeScript 2.9).

Situation as of now (VSCode 1.24.0):

- Param type is parsed correctly, allowing for [type checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking).
- Param description text doesn't show up in IntelliSense (issue reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24746)).

Comment: Looking for clarification. Are you saying that JavaScript object destructing won't be supported [directly]? We will be forced to use TypeScript to appreciate that functionality? I'm on v1.42.1 and just found that the results where nothing like the JSDoc sample. All I got was ```/**
 * 
 * @param {*} param0 
 */```