# React Hooks - JSDoc with destructured array variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsdoc3

I'm trying to JSDoc a simple React Typescript component with hooks. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way that makes JSDoc work with declared destructured arrays. There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788606/how-to-document-deconstructed-parameters-with-jsdoc) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644750/how-to-describe-destructured-object-arguments-in-jsdoc) related to destructuring object params, but these don't work for arrays.

```
/**
 * @property {boolean} 0 - documentation for isLoading
 * @property {func} 1 - documentation for setIsLoading
 */
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
```

**Update 1**: Still having trouble finding a way to document this destructure. There is a corner case where if I custom type an object, it works:

```
export type AuthFormInput = {
  /** Value of the Email input field */
  email: string;
  /** Value of the Password input field */
  password: string;
};

const [form, setForm] = React.useState<AuthFormInput>({
  email: '',
  password: ''
});

...

// JSDoc will work here
const email = form.email;
```

Comment: Did you post all the relevant code? I don't see any reference to JSDoc or a destructured array.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington JSDoc is indeed the comment block above the single line of code. The destructured array is in `const [isLoading, setIsLoading]`.

Comment: so you want to JSDoc local variable, am I right? if yes, what's the need?

Comment: @skyboyer mainly to document the component state so that the reference to it can be brought up later when it's used.

Answer (score 29):

It would help:

```
    /**
     * @typedef {Boolean} LoadingState — documentation for isLoading
     * @description Additional doc
     */
    /**
     * @typedef {Function} LoadingStateSetter — documentation for setIsLoading
     */
    /**
     * @type {[LoadingState, LoadingStateSetter]} Loading
     */
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState();
```

In this example we declare two additional types: `LoadingState` and `LoadingStateSetter`. Then we add some description for them and finally, we declare the `Loading` type for the result of `React.useState()`

You also can declare it in a more simple way like this:

```
    /**
      * @type {[Boolean, Function]} Loading
      */
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState();
```

But I didn't find a way to add a description in this case.

I've checked the description of such way of documentation in VSCode

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```js
/** @type {boolean} */
const initialState = false
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(initialState)
```

Comment: this is better because typescript would infer the type of isLoading and setIsLoading by itself +1. setIsLoading is more complex than `Function`, it is `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`

Comment: Note that this only work if there is one type that the variable can hold - meaning that if you wanted a nullable value for example, it will infer only a partial type (even if you specific the type for the variable). Kind of annoying to be honest...

Answer (score 7):

The actual best solution to be found here is by using parentheses. Otherwise jsdoc does not seem to catch it:

```js
const [authFormInput, setAuthFormInput] = useState(/** @type {AuthFormInput} */({..}));
```

Comment: this is the simplest and the best solution

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way I found is to use `types.d.ts`, since we're likely gonna need to type out more than just a `useState` and we can keep a lot of the code there for cleanliness:

```
// types.d.ts:
declare type State = string;
declare type SetState = (stateParam: State) => void;
declare type UseState = [State, SetState];

// component.jsx:
  /**
   * @type {UseState}
  */
  const [state, setstate] = useState("");
```